# Storing numeric input - Why does Java Scanner nextInt() allows "invalid" zero filled integers?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, alphanumeric, zerofill

I'm creating a phone directory which will consist of multiple `nameEntry` objects each containing a surname and a phone extension.

```
public class nameEntry {

    public String surname;
    public String number;

    public nameEntry(String surname, int number) {
        this.surname = surname.toUpperCase();
        this.number = String.format("%04d", number); 
        // converts int literal to 0 filled string of numbers
    }

    public String toString() {
        return surname + "\t" + number; //eg HOOD     0123
    }
}
```

Having read into good java practice about storing alphanumerics I have programmed the `nameEntry` objects to take an `int` as a parameter and then convert it to a zero filled `String`, because storing as `int` Objects would be inappropriate given their nature. However, this approach means that I cannot create new `nameEntry` objects with zero filled numbers by this method as it tells me the integers are invalid;

```
nameEntry e = new nameEntry(surname, 0123); //this would be flagged as wrong
```

However if I use a `Scanner nextInt(System.in)` method, is it perfectly happy with me entering a zero filled digit and then using that object to create a new `nameEntry` object.

Why is this scenario valid?

Regardless, this all seems over the top just to get a single zero filled input string - what is a better way of allowing a user to enter a single number of up to 4 characters that is either zero filled, or will be automatically zero filled after entry?

Comment: `0123` is not an integer, in Java

Comment: @GIJoe Since when it's not?

Comment: It is but as pointed by @peter.petrov , it is an octal. Hence, 08 does not exist and is not a valid integer. 0123 still exists.

Comment: @peter.petrov: It's octal, that's why

Comment: Your example would *not* be "flagged as wrong" since `0123` is a perfectly valid octal literal.

Comment: @GIJoe So octals like 0123 are not integers? What are they - Strings, Lists, Maps?

Comment: "`0123` is not a *decimal* integer in Java" might convey your point more clearly.  It certainly is *an* integer, just not the one you'd expect.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle It is 83.

Comment: @peter.petrov: It is an octal literal. `83` is a decimal integer.

Comment: @peter.petrov yes, I will buy a calculator -_-'

Comment: @davidhood2 to answer you, I don't understand why you take an int as an input and not a String? It would be easier to take a String and validate it with a regex.

Comment: @GIJoe It's an *integer value*. The fact that it's expressed in octal doesn't matter. `int foo = 0123;` is perfectly valid Java. The OP's example is also valid and will not produce an error.

Comment: @GIJoe It is an octal literal, yes. And its value is integer, not double or float or boolean or char.

Comment: @peter.petrov: Ok, fair enough

Comment: @GIJoe Now you know. And knowing is half the battle!

Comment: @DavidConrad: Haha true

Comment: And in the end, the whole octal thing is just a red herring. Java ignores leading zeroes when parsing an int from a string when the radix is 10. Everyone (including myself) got sidetracked by the (non-related) octal literal in the OP's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> storing [a phone number] as ints would be inappropriate given their nature.

So why are you reading them in as ints?  Why not use `Scanner.next()` or `Scanner.nextLine()`, since you know phone numbers aren't (conceptually) numbers?

You should expect your user to pass in exactly the phone number they expect.  Attempting to transform it (e.g. letting them leave leading 0s off and filling them in yourself) is a recipe for confusion and bugs.  Rather than transforming the user's input, add sanity checks, such as a regex, to confirm the user provided valid input.

```
public class nameEntry {
  private static final Pattern VALID_NUMBER = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}");
  private String surname;
  private String number;

  public nameEntry(String surname, String number) {
    this.surname = surname;
    if(!VALID_NUMBER.matcher(number).matches()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(number+
                " does not appear to be a valid phone number.");
    }
    this.number = number;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return surname + "\t" + number; //eg HOOD     0123
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I used int's so that, when reading them in to create the object it throws an error if you attempt to put non numerical characters, whereas if it was a String I dont know how I would achieve the equivalent effect - but you've answered that anyway so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When parsing an integer value from a `String` (including when you use a `Scanner` and its `nextInt()` method), Java simply ignores the leading zero when the radix is 10 (decimal, which is the default).

```
String bar = "0123";
int foo = Integer.valueOf(bar);
System.out.println(foo);
```

Output:

> 123

If you need to specifically exclude input that has a leading `0` then you would need to read the input as a `String` and check for yourself whether or not there's a leading zero.

Comment: @davidhood2 Under the covers all `Scanner` is doing is exactly what I posted. You'd simply check for leading zeroes *first* then parse the `String` to an `int` as shown above if that's what you want.